# Dispatch on laravel 5.6 won't run function handle(), only run construct()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, job-scheduling

Hi i try to create queue job, using queue=redis in laravel 5.2
But i've checked using log, my job only run construct() not running handle()

can you suggest what's wrong?

my dispatch scheme like this :

Controller -> dispatch -> dispatch_now() -> dispatch_now()

here is my code :

```
class LogHelper implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $transId;

    public function __construct(int $transId)
    {
        $this->transId = $transId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(){
       //do code
    }
}
```

expecting of those job was running normally like normal job and code excuted

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a queue worker. Refer to the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#running-the-queue-worker).

Comment: had already running worker, and had running job normally.
i mean, it was same base script job and why it wasn't run. does any condition that's make job won't run?